# Floating value not saving in database

Tags: php, magento

I am saving a float value and my custom column type is decimal(12,2).
But when I set 12.56 value from controller it saves int value rather than float value.

Please Help

Comment: You need to post code to have any chance of receiving help. Also include table schema.

Comment: If you insert the value in the DB interface does it save correctly? If so you need to provide the PHP code.

Comment: I tried your problem, but for me it works:
`$db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=db_name','root','pass');

$value = 12.56;

$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO test SET number=?');
$stmt->execute([$value]);`. And I declared as decimal(12,2) my `number` column.

Comment: Can it be you have a decimal point "mismatch"? I mean that your variable has the comma as decimal point but MySQL expects a point?

Comment: What's the code of you controller? Do you any ORM, maybe the value on your ORM is the problem?